# Got the exception while ran my code with sublime ：(null): can't open file '$file_basename': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, sublimetext3

```
import pandas as pd
```

import csv
for i in range(1,180):
    url = 'http://s.askci.com/stock/a/?reportTime=2017-12-31&pageNum=%s' % (str(i))
    tb = pd.read_html(url)[3]
    tb.to_csv(r'1.csv',mode = 'a',encoding = 'utf_8_sig',headers = 1,index = 0)
    print('第'+str(i)+'页爬取完成')

[image]

Comment: Please format your code as code and with correct indentation. To format your code as code, simply add 4 whitespaces in front of every line. Then, add more whitespaces to indent correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, deal that!
It was caused by the sublime.After many clicks on F5, the current py file (left editor) loses focus ~that is to say, before each F5 execution, you can click on the PY file. Then execution, there will be no error. After many clicks on F5, the current py file (left editor) loses focus ~that is, before each F5 execution, you can click on the PY file. Then execution, there will be no error.